# How to access superclass data members in java to create constructor in child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, extends

I am trying to create a constructor in a subclass which can take the values of data members of its superclass. but I don't know what is wrong here.
error is saying that 'method card is undefined for the type creditcard'

```
class card{
    int cardno;
    String cust_name;
    String bank_name;
    public card(int num,String c_name,String b_name)
    {
       cardno=num;
       cust_name=c_name;
       bank_name=b_name;
    }
    card(){}
}

class creditcard extends card{
    int limit;
    public creditcard(int num,String c_name,String b_name,int lim)
    {
        card(num,c_name,b_name);
        limit=lim;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use the keyword super instead of card. Like: super(num,c_name,b_name); This way the constructor of the super aka base aka parent class will be called.

Comment: BTW: please check on the net Java naming conventions. Like: 1. class name should be first letter uppercase 2. use camelCase instead of _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your method to the code below:

```
public creditcard(int num, String c_name, String b_name, int lim) {
super(num, c_name, b_name);
limit = lim;
}
```

super more about super keyword here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Hope this helps.